# Using 'import' statement inside script tag marked as module yields a 404 error

Tags: javascript, express, webpack, module, script-tag

I have a NodeJS project which uses Webpack for packaging and Express for serving. When a user visits my root domain, I serve them an `index.html` file which contains a `<script>` block inside the footer. This script block has a `type` of `module`.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><!--content--></head>
<body><!--content--></body>
<footer>
    <script type="module">
        import MyService from './services/my';
        // Use MyService
    </script>
</footer>
</html>
```

And of course, I have a **my.js** module at the directory specified:

```
export default class MyService { ... }
```

However, when I build, start, and visit my app (on localhost), I get the following error in my console:

> GET https://localhost:3009/services/my.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

It appears my app is trying to locate that module via the URL, rather than the code tree.

Is there something I need to configure differently with my setup to make this work? Do I need a separate entry point with Webpack? Suggestions welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's what `type="module"` and `import` do. It allows you to keep your code fragmented in the backend and only serve the parts the client needs. If you have a file at /services/my.js, you'll need to make sure express can serve it. Otherwise you need to put your js there.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to generate this html entrypoint yourself rather than using [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) from the build? Otherwise can you describe the project structure you are trying to achieve and the webpack setup you are using to get there?

Comment: (1 of 3) Right, so my setup is slightly more complicated than I indicated in my original question for brevity's sake. I do use the HtmlWebpackPlugin to generate an `index.hbs` via the `template` and `filename` options to HtmlWebpackPlugin. My express server uses the `hbs` npm package as its view engine: `app.set('view engine', 'hbs');` And with express, I have '/' rendering the `index.hbs` file Webpack produces.

Comment: (2 of 3) As for why I need to do the thing I'm doing with the embedded module script: There is a 3rd party widget my project is required to use, and their preferred way to integrate is to include a prewritten JS block on my app's main page, inside script tags. Their code inserts a new `<script>` block on my page, with the `src` attribute being the URL to their actual script. Their actual script then places an object in the global namespace that I can then reference from anywhere in my app. Does this feel like something that was done in 2000? Yes. Can I change it? No.

Comment: (3 of 3) I'm attempting to write a wrapper service around their global object that I can import and use when I want, rather than polluting the global namespace. I'm trying to import that service from within the script block. That's where I'm running into trouble, per my question.

Comment: The example setup makes it look like you are trying to include local project structure rather than webpack built structure.  My outside assumption would be to include `MyService` in the webpacked code rather than trying to creating this additional entry point.  I guess the separate load is required for the external injections to happen before your JS... maybe an standalone [chunk or entrypoint](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) for MyModule?

Comment: My main point is either rely on a static js file that's published in the webroot, or a webpack output from your project tree.  At the moment the example looks like somewhere in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Have to include the file extension.

```
import MyService from './services/my.js';
```

https://github.com/ChrisWong979/using-import-statement-inside-script-tag